# Have the KAA notifications checked the schema version when received in C SDK

Tags: kaa

I have one endpoint connected to the KAA server with the notification schema version v2. And it can receive the notification data with the verson v2 successfully.

But when I send the notification using schema version v1("EmptyData" automatically generated by KAA server), the endpoint client crashed with "segmentation fault".

It seems the C SDK generated by KAA server always treat the notification data as schema version v2.

How can I avoid this mistake using wrong data model? improve the safety of the client?

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the crash on my side.

If you believe the issue is on the Kaa Client (SDK) side, please open a bug in [Kaa Jira](http://jira.kaaproject.org/) with more information on how to reproduce the issue, logs and code snippets for Kaa team investigations.